# help with sqlite replace function

Tags: sql, sqlite, replace

am trying to update my database table that looks like this

```
name  | file_name
----------------
name1 | name1\data
```

what i want to do is, to replace all the name1 from `name` found in `file_name` column with empty string

```
update cache set
file_name=replace(file_name,name,'')
where file_name like '%'||name||"%'"
```

When i execute the query above, i get an empty recordset.

can anybody help me fix this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE cache SET file_name=replace(file_name, name, '');
```

Worked without the WHERE clause.